# Parse.com data design for Group by queries

Tags: database-design, parse-platform, nosql

Need some help with data design

I have a class called printers and they have an organization number. I also have another class called buildings. printers can be grouped under buildings. I also have users who belong to organization. so currently the following data structure

```
Organization name, organization number 
Building Name, building location, organization number 
Printer, printer details, organization number, building 
User, user name, organization number 
Message, messageID, urgency, pointer to printer
```

Users belong to an organization. Buildings also belong to an organization. 
What is the best way for the following scenario -
  **When a user logs in, he sees all his buildings with an icon showing red if any of the printers have urgent messages. Selecting a building will show him all printers.**

Do i need to make multiple parse queries?

Comment: What language, and no you just have to add parameters to the query;

Comment: thank you, I would like it in Javascript using Node.js

Comment: Do I need to do the following: Fetch the users org id, find all the buildings with that org_id, find all the printers that belong to each of the building, then find the message status for each of those printers?

Comment: Yes, if they are different classes, I will post an example answer in JS for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may do it in one call by looking for the printer status then you would decide what data to grab from the returned objects.

```
//Set query to look for buildings and printers
    var query = new Parse.Query("buildings");
    query.equalTo("orgId",currentUserOrgId); //Check this line, apply your ID names

    var query2 = new Parse.Query("printers");

    var mainQuery = Parse.Query.and(query,query2);

    mainQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " objects.");

            // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            //Grab all building names, printers and messages etc here
            var object = results[i];
            alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('printerName')); 
            //get the values you need this way        
            if (object.get('urgency') == "urgent"){
                //add to an array of urgent printers with the pointer as well
            }
            //Add more logic here to sort through the class objects and store the data you need for your application
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: But this doesnt retreive the list of buildings.  I need to show a list of buildings with an icon if any of the printers in that building have an urgent status.

Comment: Like i said, I don't know your class structure. Read the API guides on queries for more info, this is a simple question and the docs have your answer. Cheers.

Comment: Switz, sorry for the newbie question. but my class structure is defined above. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let sit down with it and see what i can do... Give it an hour.  What class are buildings in, and what is the id for that column? Also what is the id of the message and urgent status?

Comment: building are in buildings class with following structure <br> Building Name, building location, organization number, objectid for that class is the ID. for messages, again objectid is the ID and urgent is when an urgent message is received and the status for that printer needs to show red